# How to check the second click of the checkbox?

Tags: jquery

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
   $('#sale').click(function(){ 
      $('.disabledCheckboxes').prop("disabled", true);
   });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="form-check">
    <label class="form-check-label">
    <input id="sale" type="checkbox" class="form-check-input">
    <i class="input-frame"></i>
     SALE
     </label>
</div>
<div class="form-check">
    <label class="form-check-label">
    <input id="sale" type="checkbox" class="form-check-input">
    <i class="input-frame"></i>
     NOT SALE
     </label>
</div>

<div class="col-md-4 mt-3">
     <label>INPUT</label>
     <input class="form-control form-control-lg disabledCheckboxes" mask="d0/M0/0000" 
      placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy"/>
</div>
```

When I click the checkbox, jquery works. And the id I set becomes active. Thus, inputs become ineffective. But when I press it for the second time, it doesn't activate. I'm new to Jquery. How should it be done?

Comment: You should not have multiple elements with the same id `sale`, ID should always remain unqiue. Use class for this.

Comment: that's not my question. I want the feature to be removed when the checkbox is pressed again

Comment: It might not be part of your question, but it's a general thing to keep in mind that Id's shall always remain the same. It's like have 2 people with the same social security number.

Answer (score 0):

As I said in the comments, ID should always be unique, so it's a bad idea to have 2x id="sale", but to solve your question use:

```
$('.disabledCheckboxes').prop("disabled", this.checked);
```

**Demo**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#sale').click(function() {
    $('.disabledCheckboxes').prop("disabled", this.checked);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-check">
  <label class="form-check-label">
    <input id="sale" type="checkbox" class="form-check-input">
    <i class="input-frame"></i>
     SALE
     </label>
</div>
<div class="form-check">
  <label class="form-check-label">
    <input id="sale" type="checkbox" class="form-check-input">
    <i class="input-frame"></i>
     NOT SALE
     </label>
</div>

<div class="col-md-4 mt-3">
  <label>INPUT</label>
  <input class="form-control form-control-lg disabledCheckboxes" mask="d0/M0/0000" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" />
</div>
```